# How to initialize the whole ASP.NET MVC machinerie in order to test controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I have a solution with an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and a unit test project.
I have some code in some controllers that relies on the `HttpContext`:

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser = await getApplicationUser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```

When running the automated tests that exercises the previous code I get an exception since `HttpContext` is not initialized.

I need to test my ASP.NET MVC controllers **without mocking** the actual running context.

I assume that this requires to initialize the framework with a fair amount of state (populating the `HttpContext` for example) and maybe to run the tests in an IIS environement.

There is the [ASP.NET unit test project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182526%28VS.80%29.aspx), but it is [only capable of testing classic ASP.NET pages](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b53b3020-002f-40f7-aa48-b838ee454559/unit-test-for-a-webservice-vsenterprisehelperaxd?forum=vstswebtest) and not MVC controllers.

How to make sure that integration tests run in an actual ASP.NET MVC context?

Comment: Have you looked at running OWIN in an IIS Express instance? https://ruhul.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/end-to-end-testing-of-web-api-2-using-owin-and-specflow/ may be useful.